# How to get previous task name in complex workflows involving parallel tasks

Tags: activiti

I have a use case where I need to know the previous user task, excluding gateways if any in between. 
If anyone worked on similar problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a simple variable that is updated after every task in a complete event listener. The event listener has access to the Task and Execution, so you can save the id, name, assignee, whatever you want.

Then, access it in the subsequent task.

Greg

Comment: There can be multiple tasks coming to a task, so saving after every task complete wont solve this problem.

Comment: Then you can query the history tables based on process instance and sorted by task completion datetime.